# Imagemagick: How do "-define" with several parameters in it?

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

When using a batch-file with IM, I have a need of defining several parameters for "-define". My original code-line is:

`magick "inputfile" -colorspace RGB -filter Lanczos -define filter:blur=.9891028367558475 -distort Resize 1072x -quality 90 -colorspace sRGB -verbose "output.jpg"`

.. which works as desired. Now I need to add the following to the line:

`-define jpeg:dct-method=float`

However, as can be seen above, I have already initiated and occupied the -define parameter.
So how can ppl use several parameters under the -define command? What is the proper usage/syntax?

I also use FFMPEG for videos, and FFMPEG accepts combining several parameters for one command by simply using a comma "," between the parameters. Applying this on Imagemagick, just to test, will be this:

`magick "inputfile" -colorspace RGB -filter Lanczos -define jpeg:dct-method=float,filter:blur=.9891028367558475 -distort Resize 1072x -quality 90 -colorspace sRGB -verbose "output.jpg"`

Imagemagick doesn't protest when I run this. However Imagemagick is unfortunately unusually silent about however it accepts commands or not. FFMPEG on the other hand is very outspoken with this. ImageMagick also does not protest if I use double "-define" commands, like this:

`magick "inputfile" -colorspace RGB -filter Lanczos -define jpeg:dct-method=float -define filter:blur=.9891028367558475 -distort Resize 1072x -quality 90 -colorspace sRGB -verbose "output.jpg"`

So I'm not sure if I trust that either using a comma-sign or double commands works, or not. I have been scanning Imagemagicks vast helpfiles for some time now, and I find no mentioning of using two parameters within one command, or to use the same command twice.

Hoping for some more experienced opinions/directions.

thx

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed: it asks a specific syntax question. [The docs](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define) suggest that the proper syntax is to _space_-separate _multiple_ proper definitions passed to a _single_ `-define` parameter (and don't mention whether _multiple_ `-define` parameters are alternatively supported); applied to your case: `-define jpeg:dct-method=float filter:blur=.9891028367558475`

Comment: @mklement0 You cannot define two things with one `-define` statement, the docs do not say or imply that. You can have multiple `-define` parameters, per my answer below. There are 2 kinds of parameters to **ImageMagick** - *"operators"* which perform some operation on all loaded images immediately and *"settings"* which simply define a setting (which is just noted and remembered) and then it moves on. The parameter `-define` falls into the second category and there's nothing to stop you saying you want to use filter method A and furthermore blur parameters B.

Comment: P.S. I don't think it should have been closed either 

Comment: Glad to hear it re closure, @MarkSetchell. I have no experience with ImageMagick, but the linked documentation shows the following abstract syntax (note the ellipsis): `-define key{=value}...` and the following example: `magick bilevel.tif -define ps:imagemask eps3:stencil.ps`. It also states (emphasis added): "This option creates _one or more definitions_ ..."

Comment: @mklement0 I'm fairly sure the docs are wrong. I just tried `magick -size 640x480 xc: -define jpeg:extent=400kb -define tiff:tile-geometry=256x256 result.jpg` and it works fine. When i tried `magick -size 640x480 xc: -define jpeg:extent=100KB tiff:tile-geometry=256x256 result.jpg` it barfed saying `tiff:tile-geometry=256x256` is not a file.

Comment: @mklement0 Maybe OP will actually try my answer one day...

Comment: Interesting, @MarkSetchell (I'm being serious - I have no dog in this race). The linked docs have no versioning information, so I don't know if it comes down to a change between versions, but either way - given that you seem to be a knowledgeable user -  I encourage you to provide feedback on the documentation.

Comment: @mklement0 I hear you and agree. My last set of suggestions were *"in the wrong format"* and not well received. I shall try again.

Comment: @MarkSetchell:  Final - speculative - thought, reflecting on the example in the docs vs. your failing example: It looks like input file names are _operands_ rather than _option-arguments_, which - assuming that ImageMagick supports permissive (non-POSIX-compliant) intermingling of operands and options - introduces _ambiguity_: In the docs example, `magick bilevel.tif -define ps:imagemask eps3:stencil.ps`, the file-name operand is already bound by the time the `-define` option is parsed. In your example, it hasn't (`result.jpg` is placed at the very end).

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry for absence. Newbie on S.O. From the great response to my question, I learned that multiple -define parameters are working, with ImageMagick. I went with your provided solution :) Part of my uncertainty was the lack of feedback from Imagemagick executable when running the batch (it approved either way), and also my experience of lack of definite direction in the ImageMagick documentation text landscape. Finally I needed to examine the digital results of the image processing to make sure all -define parameters had been implemented, and correctly. Thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback, @Kaley. So it sounds like Mark's answer solved your problem, so I encourage you to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple `-define` parameters without issues. Each one just sets an internal variable within **ImageMagick**. You can check with:

```
magick -debug all -define xxx -define yyy ...
```